# Simple cov gem missing untested files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simplecov

Using `simple_cov` gem in a Rails app, can we have the files that we are not testing included in the report?

- If yes, how?
- If no, that files should count to the coverage percentage, right ?

Comment: If you run the whole spec folder, then the report show every controller, helper, model coverage. For any specific test it only shows that test coverage.

Comment: Using minitest and is not doing that, even when running the whole test folder.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try to edit your `config/environments/test.rb` and set this line:

`config.eager_load = false`

to `true` in this way the whole app is loaded and simplecov reads it.

Comment: this is the preferred solution and imho fixes the issue

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @koen. Does anyone know what the workaround is after that? I'm running with Minitest for what it's worth.

Comment: It jumped my coverage from 73.xx% to 85.xx%, simply eager_loading. This is kind of funny. But gist is simplecov was considering all the code ran during eager_load phase also as covered. So no files in our project had 0% coverage anymore. Not a desired behavior i think.

Answer (score 16):

Eager load the whole Rails app when running tests suite with code coverage.
Add `Rails.application.eager_load!` to `spec_helper.rb`.

Simplecov slows down tests that's why I use shell environment variable to turn it on. Usually my `spec_helper.rb`/`rails_helper.rb` looks something like this:

```
if ENV['COVERAGE']
  require 'simplecov'
  # some SimpleCov setup, e.g. formatters
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Rails.application.eager_load! if ENV['COVERAGE']
```

Comment: Actually better than the accepted answer as this doesn't affect the performance while testing without coverage.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 0.11.0 the files that should be tracked can be explicit set ([Pull Request](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/pull/422)).

For a Rails app that would be:

```rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do
  track_files '{app,lib}/**/*.rb'
end
```

Or simple use:

```rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

And the files to be tracked will be set by default ([current related code](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/blob/ba57b3c07381e7d7d83c255309f371f816bf942d/lib/simplecov/profiles/rails.rb)).